# Check if a command got sent in a specific channel

Tags: discord.py

Is there a way to check, if a command was run in a certain channel?
I want to use client.command and not the on_message event
discord.py-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `client.command`, there is a `ctx` argument passed and with `ctx.channel.id` you can get the channel id the command was run in. Then you can check

```py
if ctx.channel.id == your_channel_id_here:
    # do whatever you want
```